# What is var file php is referring to

Tags: php, session, openshift

I deployed an PHP app on OpenShift, things are kinda working but in my php.log i am constantly seeing `[error] [client IP_ADR] File does not exist: /var/lib/openshift/.../app-root/runtime/repo/public/var, referer: SOME_URL`
SOME_URL is different most of the time, I thought it had to do something with sessions, but sessions are working (and I changed session save path). What is the `var` file and why are pages referring to it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the app is probably trying to write to a log file in a directory that doesn't exist. Check the full path, create any dirs/files you need, and set the rights correctly for the PHP user to write to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That URL is most likely the [HTTP Referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer). When a user visits your site by clicking on a link, the page containing the link will be send along with the request in a HTTP header. This gets logged by your webserver.

But why the error?

It could be that some part of your html/css/js is trying to include some file that does not exist, or maybe some bot is just visiting your site looking for a var file that does not exist.

Try to visit a non exiting path on your site. Do you get the same kind of message then?

Comment: "It could be that some part of your html/css/js is trying to include some file that does not exist" - that was the problem. Thanks!